# Laravel Api - how to put like and dislike

Tags: php, laravel, api

I’m trying to create an API request for like and dislike in my Laravel project:

> Route::post('like', ‘Api\ApiController@like’);

The function in the ApiController look like this:

```
$post = \App\Post::find($request->id);

$social = SocialPost::where([['user_id', '=', ($request->user_id)],['post_id', '=', ($request->id)]])->first();

$unsocial = SocialPost::where([['user_id', '=', ($request->user_id)],['post_id', '=', ($request->id)],['like', '=', 0]])->first();

if ($social) {
    if ($unsocial) {
        $social->update(['like' => 1]);
        return json_encode(array('status' => true,'msg'=>'like')); 
    }
    else {
        $social->update(['like' => 0]);
        return json_encode(array('status' => true,'msg'=>'dislike')); 
    }
}
else {
    $join = new \App\SocialPost;
    $join->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $join->post_id = $post->id;
    $join->like = 1;
    $join->view = 0;
    $join->creator = 1;
    $join->save();
    return json_encode(array('status' => true,'msg'=>'New table')); 
}
```

The problem is that the first If statement works but the second doesn't. If the row already exists he always put '1' for 'like' also if the message that return is 'dislike'.

Comment: _Side note:_ There's not reason for putting the variables in parentheses when adding them to an array. it just makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that should work with you.

```php
<?php

// Get the post from the database
$post = \App\Post::find($request->id);

// Find the SocialPost record if it exists,
// if it doesn't create a new one with no likes
$socialPost = SocialPost::firstOrCreate(
    ['user_id' => $request->user_id, 'post_id' => $post->id],
    ['user_id' => $request->user_id, 'post_id' => $post->id, 'likes' => 0, 'view' => 0, 'creator' => 1],
);

// Declare an empty variable that will determine if
// the post is being "liked" or "disliked"
$postAction = '';

// Determine if the post has likes or not
if ($socialPost->likes > 0)
{
    // The post has at least 1 like
    $postAction = 'dislike';

    // Decrement the likes by 1
    $socialPost->decrement('likes', 1);
}
else
{
    // The post has 0 likes
    $postAction = 'like';

    // Increment the likes by 1
    $socialPost->increment('likes', 1);
}

// Determine if this was a new SocialPost record
if ($socialPost->wasRecentlyCreated)
{
    // Override the post action as "New table"
    $postAction = 'New table';
}

// Return the goods
return json_encode(['status' => true, 'msg' => $postAction]);
```

Explanation

You can determine if the SocialPost record exists, or create a new one - all in a single line using `firstOrCreate` referenced in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods). The first array parameter takes in what you are looking for, and the second array paramater takes in what should be created if the first parameter turned up nothing

```php
// Find the SocialPost record if it exists,
// if it doesn't create a new one with no likes
$socialPost = SocialPost::firstOrCreate(
    ['user_id' => $request->user_id, 'post_id' => $post->id],
    ['user_id' => $request->user_id, 'post_id' => $post->id, 'likes' => 0, 'view' => 0, 'creator' => 1],
);
```

Then you can clean up the adding or subtracting likes by using `increment` or `decrement` referenced in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#increment-and-decrement).

```php
// Determine if the post has likes or not
if ($socialPost->likes > 0)
{
    // Decrement the likes by 1
    $socialPost->decrement('likes', 1);
}
else
{
    // Increment the likes by 1
    $socialPost->increment('likes', 1);
}
```